# Как увеличить число в диве?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Для увеличения числа в блоке использую скрипт:

```
$('.class').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: 12 }, {
            duration: 1000,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function () {
                $this.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
            }
        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Yy6r6/3/

Как можно увеличить число, если одна часть числа в тэге ?

Например, число 7548:

```
<div class="figure"><span>7</span>548</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо создать эти части в коде, например:

```js
$('.Count').each(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  jQuery({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: $this.text() }, {
    duration: 5000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function () {
      var number = Math.ceil(this.Counter).toString();
      $this.html("<span class='red'>" + number.slice(0,-3) + "</span>" + number.slice(-3));
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="Count">1500</span>
<br/>
<span class="Count">2000</span>
<br/>
<span class="Count">15000</span>
```

Comment: Спасибо, не думал, что всё так просто.